# Let in imperative form which result in suggestion / proposal

Tags: spoken-english, reported-speech

> 1. Direct speech: *He suggested to me, "Let us go to market.*"

Indirect Speech:
(A) *He suggested to me to go to market.*
(B) *He suggested to me that we should go to market.*

> 2. *He said to me, "Let us purchase this house."*

(A) *He proposed to me to purchase that house.*
(B) *He proposed to me that we should purchase that house.*

Which is correct in each of these examples, A or B?

Comment: Please add some details which you think is correct, and why?  Otherwise this question will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: In first and second B is correct option but in one of the answers by lawrence-c has mentioned instead of we , they should be used. Here is the link.https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43443/reported-speech-if-sentence-starts-with-let

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **(B) is correct.** *Suggest* doesn't use the infinitive (*to go)*. Usually, it uses the [subjunctive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive), which is used in clauses containing *that*. It can also use [gerunds](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm).

> I suggest that we **go** *(subjunctive)* to the bank.
>
> I suggest **going** *(gerund)* to the bank.

2. **(B) is correct.** *Propose* can use the infinitive *(to purchase)*, but in order to determine the correct sentence in this instance, one must take away the indirect object *(me)*:

> He proposed to purchase that house.
>
> He proposed that we should purchase that house.

In the direct speech, the speaker uses *us*, indicating that you and other people are purchasing the house together. Sentence A doesn't convey this at all; it states that only he is purchasing the house.

Comment: In first and second B is correct option but in one of the answers by lawrence-c has mentioned instead of we , they should be used. Here is the link.https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43443/reported-speech-if-sentence-starts-with-let

Comment: @asr09 You can't use _they_ when you are part of the suggestion. It would make no sense.

Comment: If the subject of the first part of the sentence is no longer "I", but a third-person pronoun such as "he", in that case you use "they" for the second part of the sentence.

    He wished his friend good morning and proposed that they should go for a picnic that day.          Please check this link this answer is by LawrenceC for the same type of question

Comment: @asr09 Yes, because **you**'re not involved. LawrenceC says that it in his answer. If **you** wished your friend good morning and proposed that **they** should go for a picnic (including you), that would make no sense.

Comment: I understood your explanation but :LawrenceC is saying that:If the subject of the first part of the sentence is no longer "I", but a third-person pronoun such as "he", in that case you use "they" for the second part of the sentence.                                                                                          I just need to ask  in my question which you have answered  if I use they when he is the subject , it would be right or wrong.

Comment: @asr09 It depends on who is in the conversation. If someone suggests that if a sentence starts with _he_, you use _they_, they are completely wrong. What if _he_ told _me_? _He_ and _me_ = _us_, not _they_.